# how to set IntelliJ default idk location?

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8

I have been trying to follow the steps of the setting up the idk in IntelliJ by doing:

```
1) file
2) project
3)project sdk
```

And also in gradle settings I also point to the correct SDK but then I get a popup message saying:

```
Gradle sync failed: The idk installation is invalid. Selected idk location is:

C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.13
```

I don't know where IntelliJ is getting idk-11.0.13 from. I have set it everywhere to 1.8 anb when I try to set it manually I get some Android SDK issue:
The android SDK location cannot be at the filesystem root.

The problem is not in Android. it is plain Java

Comment: Set SDK in the project structure: https://i.imgur.com/5vC6E0Y.png

Comment: I did that already. Same issue. I get this gradle sync issue. The JDK installation is invalid

Comment: share your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

show you settings and project build.gradle file ,
and also you can check your IntelliJ config.
location is `Project Structure- Project - Project SDK`